# Run .NET app within same session with aws-vault

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-vault

I need to retrieve `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to initialize `AmazonSQSClient`.

I proceed login via powershell using `aws-vault exec [profile] --debug -- powershell` command but as far as I know it adds environment variables only for one specific session and I can't access them from my .NET application.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you tell a little bit where you are running your .NET application? Is it a web-app, desktop app or console one? Why using PowerShell in .NET app?

Comment: It's a background service (console application). I don't really use PowerShell with .NET app, just used it to try to login in vault on my machine - it works, now I wanna use credentials from vault in my application - no matter what I'll need to use

Comment: Are you running this background service on EC2?

Comment: Not yet, now I need to run it locally at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution in running aws-vault and application through batch script.

- Create file in `.cmd` resolution, like `run.cmd`;
- Put the following content there:

```
@echo off 
set AWS_PROFILE=your AWS configuration profile name
aws-vault exec %AWS_PROFILE% -- path to your .exe file 2>&1
```